# Need to know the server timing of retrieving the newest data from all Jawbone UP users

Tags: jawbone

could you kindly let me know the timing of Jawbone data server updates the individual newest data from all users? 
And is it possible to take the newest Jawbone server data through API anytime? 
I need to know above information for our Jawbone app.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, so I'll try my best to answer it.

The API will always have the latest data available, a call to any of the endpoints will get you an authorised users recent data for each type of data tracked. I hope this helps.